# How to find invisible Mixed Content issue on secured website?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, https, vue-router

I deployed a basic `PWA` application on `NGINX` server, created by using Vue `CLI`.
instead of using `history` mode for Vue router, `hash` mode is selected.

Although website is secured:

[image]

I have the following errors and not sure what I can do about it. Anyone maybe got already such error?:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com/service-worker.js' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://example.com/'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
Fetch API cannot load https://example.com/index.html. Redirect failed.
service-worker.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

**==== UPDATED ====**

Could the following lines break the HTTPS ?:

[image]

**==== UPDATED ====**

Just to make sure for everyone, there is no SSL break issues caused by having SVG files "http" meta-tags. No need to change those files.

Comment: Does your app works fine using history mode? What is your nginx config?

Comment: it works fine both on *hash* and *history* mode on local environment only, but not on **NGINX** server. That's why I switched from history to hash mode to avoid making changes to servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just send request from `no secure` url to `secure` ones. you can check this mozilla documentation for deeper informations : 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content.

Comment: please, check my updated question, I've pinned a screenshot

Comment: yeah it's a `http`, you check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content. you can use `https://www.w3.org/2000/svg`

Comment: Problem was caused by this line, located in `registerServiceWorker.js`: `register('${process.env.BASE_URL}service-worker.js', {...`

Comment: Good to know Thanks